# convert iPhone app to universal app

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, ios-universal-app

I want to convert my iPhone app into universal application. So, what I've done is simply duplicated target into iPad target and created nibs for iPad, also I've specified the type of app as universal. But when I run my new created target it loads only iPad nibs. So, how can I make my app to load necessary nibs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Don't copy the target. Set the Device of your target to Universal and add code to load the nibs depending on the device your app is running on. More on that you can find [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just select target, then select general. In `Deployment Info`, select `Universal` instead of `iPhone`, like the pic below.
[image]